# Where should I configure software installed by 3rd-party chef recipes?

Tags: chef, vagrant

I'm provisioning a Vagrant virtual machine with Chef and it's amazing, but I'm unsure where I should put code to configure software installed by 3rd-party chef recipes.

For example, I'm installing NGINX with [this recipe](https://github.com/opscode/cookbooks/tree/master/nginx) but I need to configure the default virtual host to serve content from `/vagrant/public` instead of `/var/www/nginx-default`.

Should I change the template of the 3rd-party recipe, or create another recipe that reconfigures it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

Since the writing fo this question, Opscode has split out their repository structure to be one-repo-per-cookbook to make the project a lot clearer.

The up-to-date released, stable nginx cookbook can be found here: http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/nginx

As to serve web pages from an alternate container:

The convention to do something like this would be to write a simpler cookbook, that leverages the `nginx` cookbook but provides you with a way to "do what you want".

Since the default nginx installation drops a config file and sets the source dir, a way I would do this in a "wrapper" cookbook is:

1. Create my cookbook
2. Declare `depends 'nginx'` in `metadata.rb`
3. In my cookbook's `attributes/default.rb`, set the following attribute to false:

   ```
   default['nginx']['default_site_enabled'] = false
   ```
4. In my `recipes/default.rb`, have:

   ```
   include_recipe 'nginx'

   cookbook_file '/etc/nginx/sites-available/mycustomwebapp'

   nginx_site 'mycustomwebapp' do
     action :enable
   end
   ```
5. Create an nginx conf file that looks like this in `files/default/mycustomwebapp`:

   ```
   server {
       root /vagrant/public;
       index index.html index.htm;
           blah blah...
   }
   ```

Then you should be good to go!